# Big Omega of a while loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I am learning about running times now and I am having trouble wrapping my head around Big Omega time. So, its safe to say that Big Omega of binary search is `Ω(1)`, because it takes at least constant time.

What if let's say I have a while loop `i < n`, then its `O(n)`, but does that mean that its `Ω(1)` or `Ω(sqrt(n))` or something else because we can say that it takes at least constant time? I just don't understand, its straightforward with upper bound, but lower bound confuses me a lot.

I am confused about this code. Can we say that its lower bound time is `Ω(sqrt(n))` or perhaps `Ω(log n)`, because it can do at least as good?

```
i=1
while(i<n)
 i+i
end
```

Comment: In this particular case the code is $\Theta(n)$ (assuming you meant `i = i+1`).

Comment: You are changing the question, though, and this makes it harder to answer – each revision will need its own answer. Perhaps you need to do this interactively with a teaching assistant in person, rather than online; the stackexchange format is suitable for such prolonged discussions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant i gets doubled. Like i was 1 on first iteration, then its 2, then 4, then 8 and so on on each iteration. I should have written it another way.

Comment: Then it's $\Theta(\log n)$. You see – the running time depends on the actual code.

Comment: I see... So if its  Θ(logn) then its lower bound is Ω(log n) too?

Comment: It has many lower bounds. It's $\Omega(1),\Omega(\log\log n),\Omega(2\log n)$... and also $\Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: What about Ω(sqrt(n))?

Comment: No, not that one.

Comment: Moderator notice: Please do not delete answered questions, even if you're able to. This is a [question and answer site](/tour), not a homework support site. Answers on this site are not just for you, they're for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Any code that gets executed takes time $\Omega(1)$. That's the most you can say if you don't know anything more about the code. For example, if all your know is that your loop has the form `while i < n ...`, then it could be that $i = n$, so the loop immediately terminates.

Here are some concrete cases in which we can calculate the complexity:

```
i = 1
while i < n:
  i = i + 1
```

This runs in time $\Theta(n)$.

```
i = 1
while i < n:
  i = i + i
```

This runs in time $\Theta(\log n)$.

```
i = 1
j = 1
while i < n:
  i = i + j
  j = j + 1
```

This runs in time $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$.

See if you can prove all these claims.

Comment: So let's say I am increasing my i in the while i < n loop. Can I say that the lower bound will be Ω(sqrt(n))? Since I update my i inside a while loop and it can do as good as Ω(sqrt(n))?

Comment: No, you can't say anything better in general since, for example, $i$ might be larger than $n$ to begin with; or some instruction might say $i$ to equal $n$ during the first iteration. You can't get a meaningful time lower bound without looking at the code, any more than you can do the same for time upper bounds.